# ArgumentError wrong number of arguments (1 for 3..4)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arguments, erb

I get an ArgumentError for *line #3* in my views/-/new.html.erb file that states:

"wrong number of arguments (1 for 3..4)"

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <%= form.label :category %>
    <%= form.select "category", options_from_collection_for_select([{1 => 'Food'}, {2 => 'Entertainment'}]) %>
</div>
```

The Application trace states:

app/views/events/new.html.erb:14:in `block in _app_views_events_new_html_erb__1569841425540097418_70204987081640'
app/views/events/new.html.erb:5:in`_app_views_events_new_html_erb__1569841425540097418_70204987081640'

**erb:14** is *line #3* above, and **erb:5** is

```
<%= form_for @event do |form| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is being thrown by `options_from_collection_for_select([{1 => 'Food'}, {2 => 'Entertainment'}])`

`[{1 => 'Food'}, {2 => 'Entertainment'}]` is an array being passed as one argument to `options_from_collection_for_select` method; hence the error message.

The correct form for calling the `options_from_collection_for_select` helper method is

```
options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)
```

See more details and usage examples at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off using `options_for_select`, which will work with the arguments you've provided and just replace the `options_from_collection_for_select` in your code. The documentation for which can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select).

You need to decide whether you want the number (1, 2 etc.) or the word (Food, Entertainment etc.) to be the "value" which reaches your back-end. For example:

```
options_for_select({'Food' => 1, 'Entertainment' => 2})
```

The output of the above in HTML would be as follows:

```
<option value="1">Food</option>
<option value="2">Entertainment</option>
```

---

The [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select) method requires 3 arguments. You've only provided one: `[{1 => 'Food'}, {2 => 'Entertainment'}]`. Your second argument should be a method/attribute on each object in the collection which represents the "value", the third should be the label for that value.